# Puppet on a Debian Wheezy machine Unmet Dependencies: Facter

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, vagrant, puppet

I am attempting to create a Puppet master server on a Raspberry Pi, but every time I attempt to install the package "puppetmaster-passenger" I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install puppetmaster-passenger

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    puppetmaster-passenger : Depends: puppetmaster-common (= 3.6.2-1puppetlabs1) but it is not going to be intalled
                             Depends: facter (>= 1.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm working with a brand new installation of Debian Wheezy 7.5 and have run apt-get update. I believe the issue is that one of the dependencies of facter is dmidecode, but dmidecode is not supported on ARM software. I've found a guide for removing the dependency for older versions of puppet, but nothing very recent (most recent: http://blog.csanchez.org/2014/01/23/installing-puppet-3-in-a-beaglebone-or-raspberry-pi/). What does this mean for getting the Raspberry Pi setup as a Puppet master server? If all I need to do to solve this issue is recompile facter without the dependency, could someone give me advice on how to do that? Here is a directory with all of the facter versions: http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/precise/main/f/facter/ (I'll need to run a version >= 1.7.0)

Comment: Raspberry...how important is it for you to use packaged versions of the software? You may find the Puppet and Facter Ruby gems to be an easier choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've configured puppetlabs APT repositories:

e.g. `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs.list`:

```
# Puppetlabs products
deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com wheezy main
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com wheezy main

# Puppetlabs dependencies
deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com wheezy dependencies
deb-src http://apt.puppetlabs.com wheezy dependencies
```

You can simply install puppet in few steps:

1. `wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb`
2. `dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-wheezy.deb`
3. `apt-get update`
4. `apt-get install puppetmaster-passenger`

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, I hope this command will surely work for you.

> sudo apt-get install puppet=3.7.1-1puppetlabs1
>   puppet-common=3.7.1-1puppetlabs1